# Ввод пароля PasswordField

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно сделать для `passwordfield`, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку входа выскакивало сообщение "Не введен пароль"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pass = new JPasswordField(10);
pass.addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            if(e.getKeyChar()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
                OKButton.doClick();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if(e.getKeyChar()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
                выскакивает сообщение "Не введен пароль"
            }  

        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            //Do Nothing
        }

});
```

Comment: @Виктор в гугл отправлять нельзя, на поиск по сайту можно.